# I am getting stack trace error and can't resolve it

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am getting the following error and i cant figure out what do to.

```
Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
    at L (index.js:1)
    at Y (index.js:1)
    at index.js:1
    at index.js:1
    at o (index.js:1)
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Post from "./Post";
import { db, auth } from "./firebase";
import { Button, Modal, Input } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50;
  const left = 50;

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
  };
}
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: "2px solid #000",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));

function App() {
  

    const classes = useStyles();
      const [modalStyle] = React.useState(getModalStyle);
      const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
      const [username, setUsername] = useState();
      const [password, setPassword] = useState();
      const [email, setEmail] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, post: doc.data() })));
    });
  }, []);
  const signUp = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
  return (
    // header
   

     <div className="app">
          <Modal open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
            <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
              <form action="" className="app-signup">
                <center>
                  <img
            

    src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png"
                alt="instagram"
                className="app-headerImage"
              />
            </center>
            <Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="userName"
              value={username}
              onChange={(e) => 
             setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="email"
              value={email}
         

     onChange={(e) => 
              setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              type="password"
              placeholder="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => 
            setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button onClick= 
         {signUp}>signUp</Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>
      <div className="app-header">
        <img
          src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png"
          alt="instagram"
          className="app-headerImage"
        />
      </div>
      <Button onClick={() => 
      setOpen(true)}>Signup</Button>
      {posts.map(({ post, id }) => {
        const { userName, caption, imageUrl } = post;
        return (
          <Post
            key={id}
            userName={userName}
            caption={caption}
            imageUrl={imageUrl}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
    //posts

    //posts
  );
}
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Seems a most unhelpful error message. Try commenting out nearly the entirety of `App` and render something simple, like "hello world", and incrementally add back in one function or component at-a-time until it breaks again. This should at least help you narrow down what is flipping out on you. Repeat process on narrower and narrower scope until you find the suspect function/line-of-code/component.

Comment: @DrewReese everything whas working fine until i addded my signup function

Comment: If you remove `onClick={signUp}` from the `Button`, and add `onSubmit={signUp}` and remove `action=''` on the `form` element does it still repro? Does `auth` have a `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function to call? Does *it* return a Promise to chain from? Can you include that firebase auth object for us to look at?

Comment: @DrewReese in useState of email, password and username. now i have intially set it equal to empty string which resolved the issue

Comment: Ok, sounds like your issue is resolved, I'm voting to close as unreproducible/caused by typo. Cheers.